# Image rendered differently in firefox than in chrome

Tags: image, firefox, web, gimp

First, please tell me if this belongs in another community, but since the problem happens in a browser I felt more appropriate to post here than in graphic design.

I bought a theme to make a quick website, but wanted the provided background-image to be a bit lighter. Armed with gimp and limited knowledge, I fiddled with the brightness/contrast and came to a satisfying result. I saved the file with a simple ctrl-S (didn't change the filetype or anything).

In chrome the result is as expected. In firefox, somehow the contrast seems way up and the image looks much more purple?

Here is a screenshot of the problem, left is in gimp, middle is in firefox, right is in chrome.

[image: Screenshot of my problem]

Here is the file, not in a screenshot:

[image: original file]

I am very curious as to why this is happening, and how to fix it it, because the result in firefox in far inferior than in chrome!

Thanks in advance to anybody who can help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type in about:config on your Firefox address bar.

Then type color_management. This will bring a couple of fields which may be causing your issue:

**gfx.color_management.display_profile**

This is the path to your monitor profile (wrong path may be one cause)

**gfx.color_management.mode**

Possible values are:

0 - Disable color management.

1 - Enable color management for all rendered graphics. (Recommended)

2 - Enable color management only for tagged images only. (Default)

After changing this settings you should restart Firefox to see the difference.

You can also test your browser with this tool to pinpoint the problem
http://cameratico.com/tools/web-browser-color-management-test/

To remove the color profile embedded in the image, install png crush and run the command:

```
pngcrush -rem gAMA -rem cHRM -rem iCCP -rem sRGB InputFile.png OutputFile.png
```

This will remove all color correction data from the file.

Comment: Thank you! The setting was set to 2, by setting it to 0, my image now displays correctly! That must mean my image is "tagged", do you know how to "untag" it, so other firefox users see the image correctly?

Comment: sRGB is the default color-profile of GIMP. You may want to remove the color profile with a tool such as pngcrush:  [Download](http://pmt.sourceforge.net/pngcrush/) [reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pngcrush). Something like pngcrush -rem -force gAMA -rem cHRM -rem iCCP -rem sRGB OldFile.png NewputFile.png should do it.

Comment: Thank you! I first tried to download color profiles for gimp using color.org but all the download links seemed dead... So I used pngcrushed as you suggested, use the command pngcrush -rem gAMA -rem cHRM -rem iCCP -rem sRGB InputFile.png OutputFile.png and now my image is fixed for firefoxes with default configuration! I edited your answer to add your solution.

Answer (score -1):

Since Firefox is not known for such issue ... I would suggest to [clear your cache](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-clear-firefox-cache?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=How%20to%20clear%20the%20cache) of your browser and try again. Potentially the image in Firefox is still the one you had before playing with contrast ... does it seems possible ?

To perform such action :

> ### Clear the cache
>
> - Click the menu button  New Fx Menu and choose Preferences.
> - Select the Advanced panel.
> - Click on the Network tab.
> - In the Cached Web Content section, click Clear Now.
> - Clear Cache Mac1
> - Close the Preferences window.

Any improvement? :D